# calculate power of two numbers iterative solution must be logn

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the power of 2 numbers in `O(log n)`, I receive wrong answer for the input:  6.9 to the power -4.

Answer should be : 0.000441168

I received 4.41167627772402E-4

I based on code from [this website](https://www.techiedelight.com/power-function-implementation-recursive-iterative/)

I added the option for negative power, if pow is negative I return 1/x^pow

why I received wrong answer, any ideas?

here is my code:

```
  public static double exp(double x, int pow) {
        double res = 1;
        boolean f = false;
        if (pow < 0) {
            pow *= (-1);
            f = true;
        }
        while (pow > 0) {
            // If pow is odd,
            // multiply
            // x with result
            if ((pow & 1) == 1)
                res = res * x;

            // pow  must be even now
         
                pow = pow >> 1; // pow = pow /2

            x = x * x; // Change x to x^2
        }
        if (!f)
            return res;
        else
            return 1 / res;
    }
```

Comment: What answer do you receive?

Comment: ... but that is the correct answer.

Comment: @bill: that looks like the same number you claim should be returned, so what is the problem?

Comment: Your code returns 4.41167627772402E-4 which is another representation of  0.000441168. I don't see any problem.

Comment: I received 4.41167627772402E-4 but answer should be 0.000441168

Comment: It's time to learn scientific notation.

Comment: How to convert the answer to the regular notation then?

Comment: Have a look at [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java's `double` is represented in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). In other words, `double` cannot represent `0.000441168` exactly: instead represent nearest value.